# Why $\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^5)^\frac{1}{5}(1-x^7)^\frac{1}{7}\, dx=0$?

Tags: calculus

When I tried to approximate

\begin{matrix} \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^5)^\frac{1}{5}(1-x^7)^\frac{1}{7}\, dx \end{matrix}
I kept getting answers that were really close to 0, so I think it might be true. But why? When I ask Mathematica, I get a bunch of symbols I don't understand!

Comment: It is not equal to $0$. It is the integral of  a continuous function which is positive in $(0,1)$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense.  On that interval, the function is entirely positive (equal to $1$ at $x=0$) and only touches the horizontal axis at $x=1$.  You can see, just by plugging some values in, that it never goes negative to balance out the positive.

Comment: You should be getting something close to 1. $(1-x^a)^{1/a}$ is almost 1 from $x:[0, 1]$ for large a.

Answer (score 5):

That integral is not zero because it is the integral over $[0,1]$ of a continuous function which is positive in $[0,1)$.

Moreover, by concavity, for $n\geq 1$, and for all $x\in [0,1]$, 
$$(1-x^n)^{1/n}\ge 1-x.$$
Hence, more generally, for $n,m\geq 1$,
$$\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^n)^{1/n}(1-x^m)^{1/m}\, dx\geq
\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^2\, dx=\int_{0}^{1} x^2\, dx=\frac{1}{3}$$
which is not "really close to zero" (compare with [WA's computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int((1-x%5E5)%5E(1%2F5)*(1-x%5E7)%5E(1%2F7),x%3D0..1);)).

Answer (score 3):

If $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and $ \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$, then we have:

$ \int_0^1 f(x) dx=0 \iff f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1].$

Consequence: $\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^5)^\frac{1}{5}(1-x^7)^\frac{1}{7}\, dx >0$.